# Select all elements but one with given index from std::vector?

Tags: c++, stdvector, std

Given a std::vector, for example of ints

`std::vector vec{10, 20, 30}`

how to select all items except of with given index, for example `int i=1` resulting

`std::vector {10, 30}`?

Comment: @closevoter What "details or clarity" does this question need?

Comment: `vec.erase(vec.begin() + i)`. If you want a new vector, just copy the original vector and do the erase operation.

Comment: Is that a new vector, or are you changing the existing vector?

Comment: @Haoliang yes, the desired behavior is not to modify the original data, any ways to do it in another ways than to explicitly copying it? one-liner maybe?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie -- as I understand, it's in place

Comment: @Sengiley *the desired behavior is not to modify the original data* -- Where are you going to store the new data if it can't be copied somewhere?  Either the original vector will be changed in place, or the original vector stays the same, and the results of the erasure will show up in a new vector.

Comment: Do you need a new vector, or do you just want to iterate over all elements except the one?

Comment: *in place* and *not modify original data* are contradictory, at least from my understanding of those terms.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to "select" values from the original vector, I would create another vector with all the new values.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    vector<int> vect{ 10, 20, 30 };

    vector<int> selected;

    int i = 1;

    for (int j = 0; j < vect.size(); j++) {
        if (j != i) {
            selected.push_back(vect[j]);
        }
    }

    // Added so you can check the new values
    for (int z = 0; z < selected.size(); z++) {
        cout << selected[z] << " ";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

However, if you want to erase values from your original vector I would recommend using the vector.erase method (research the documentation).

Comment: I'd add `.reserve()`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a function for it where you can pass the vector and index and it will return you the new vector without that index element.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;


// returns a new vector without the v[index]

 vector<int> getElementsExceptIndex(vector<int> v, int index){
    vector<int> newVector;
    for(auto &x:v ){
     if(( &x - &v[0]) != index)
      newVector.push_back(x);
   }
    return newVector;
}

int main() {
   vector<int> originalVector{ 10, 20, 30 ,33,53};
   int index=1;
   
   auto RemovedIndexVector = getElementsExceptIndex(originalVector,index);
   
   for(auto item:RemovedIndexVector)
     cout<<item<<" ";
    return 0;
}
// Output - 10 30 33 53
```

Hope this helps